# How to get replacement pattern for Search API's fulltext search in global text area header

Tags: views, search, tokens

In Drupal 7, I'm currently using the default core search, and a view for node search results. I have a global text to pull in the replacement pattern for the term that were searched for. I get the token by adding the contextual filter `Search: Search Terms` I am using the replacement pattern `%1` as seen in the picture:

[image]

Then I put `<span class="MY-CLASS">You searched for:</span> <b> %1 </b>` in my `global text` to display the keywords that were searched for:

[image]

This all works great for Drupal core search, but I am not finding a way to do this with the view in Search API? I am using Database Service, and a view built from the database index I created. I have tried to find a field such as keywords for the full text search, but since the view is based off of indexed content, I am not able to get those type of fields added, to make them available for tokens, even via relationships. Maybe there is a better way to build the view?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having here is my view that I was trying to build for search API was using a full text search **exposed filter** rather than a **contextual filter**. The contextual filter provides the `search term title` and `search term input` tokens that are pictured above. The exposed filter will not produce them. Live and learn.

EDIT: There is a bit of a workaround I found but it was an implementation I would not recommend. I was using Drupal core search blocks with Search API view's contextual filters together. I was able to add the contextual filter, get the token, then remove the contextual filter. That somehow allowed the token to work in that context.