# How to get the input value with preprocess from a Fulltext Search Filter exposed form

Tags: 7, views, hooks

For **Drupal 7** I found a workaround to a similar situation [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/292342/how-to-get-replacement-pattern-for-search-apis-fulltext-search-in-global-text-a/292395#292395), when combining Core search block forms and search api contextual filters. This "workaround" won't work when using Search API, if you don't want the Contextual Filter in your view.

**My current setup:**
I am using Search API, with a database server, and displaying the results with a Views page. I am using **Search: Fulltext search (exposed)** and **Exposed form in block:Yes** for the search block form.

**What I am trying to achive:**
I would like to put *what was searched for* in the Header of the view, and also at the top of No Results Behavior like this:

"*You searched for **bananas***"

**The problem:**
When using **Search: Fulltext search (exposed)**, the replacement patterns for the input value are not available in the **Global Text Area**. They are only available by adding a Fulltext Search **Contextual Filter**. There is an issue for this with a patch for Drupal 8 [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2761273).

**My question:**
Is there a `views_pre_render` or some other hook that can be used for the Header or No Results region to output the value that was input into the **Search: Fulltext search (exposed)** form?

There is a [dev module](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/stefanos.petrakis/2666048) to create a token, but it only works for the Results Summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not exactly what you're asking for, but the one way to approach this is to use `hook_preprocess_views_view(&$variables)` and modify the contents of the header, or add a variable containing the string you want and then it in above/below the header in a views-view.tpl.php template override. If the search string isn't available through `$variables`, you can probably grab it from the url since it's likely included as a query string.

To get the query string from the url and add it to the template variables you'd do something like the following in your module or theme:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_hook()
 */
function my_module_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  // Get the query string from the url.
  // it will be on something like ?the_search_string=big+banana.
  $search_string_raw = $_GET['the_search_string'];
  
  // Decode the url to remove special chars
  $search_string_decoded = urldecode($search_string_raw);

  // Add it to $variables so it's available in views-view.tpl.php
  $variables['search_string'] = $search_string_decoded;
}
```

This will make the search_string available in views-view.tpl.php. You can then print it in there with

```
<?php if($search_string): ?> 
  <?php print $search_string ?>
<?php endif; ?>

// or

<?php

if($search_string) {
  print $search_string;
}
```

To clarify how hook_preprocess_hook works -- the first "hook" is your module name, and the second is the name of the template that you're targeting. Since we are targeting views-view.tpl.php, we use hook_preprocess_views_view.

In general, the easiest way to get started inspecting php variables is to dump them to the screen. For Drupal 7, I'd recommend installing https://www.drupal.org/project/kint on your site. This will let you print variables to the screen to help you dig into their values and see what's in there. You'd do like:

```
function my_module_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  kint($variables);
  // or
  kpr($variables['header'])
}
```

Then you can see what's actually inside of `$variables` and grab/modify the values in there.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! If I provided you with better information, could you spin up an example hook to try?

Comment: Also, if I grab it from the URL it will have + signs in it. ie "you searched for banana+bread+muffins"

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really have a good way to set up a dummy Search API instance on D7 at the moment so that'd be tough. The header element should be in `$variables['header']` so that's what you'd tweak to print it out without a template override. With the override you could add like `$variables['search_string']` then print `$search_string` in the template. You're right that the search string would have things like + signs -- you'd can use urldecode() (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to deal with that, then maybe ucwords() or ucfirst() for capitalization.

Comment: I don't know how to write hooks from scratch, I can copy paste and tinker, that's about it. Even a try this template or pointing to docs would help. I could handle modifying a view.tpl.php template, but I would need to know how to get the actual correct variable in the and print properly. Like, do i use ```$variable['search-string']``` in the tpl file or in a custom module?

Comment: Edited my answer to hopefully give you some extra context

Comment: Looks promising! I'll have a look and follow up. Thanks very much! Are ```search_string``` and ```search_string_raw``` the actual variables, or do I need to find those?

Comment: It looks like from the answer, in $_GET['search_string'] I am supposed to replace ```search_string``` with the string from the url. I'm guessing that I need to use a wildcard where the ```big+banana``` would be.

Comment: `$search_string` and `$search_string_raw` are arbitrary -- they don't exist at all before they are set to equal something. You could rename them to absolutely anything and the snippet would work exactly the same. In `$_GET['foo']` you'd replace `foo` with whatever is directly to the right of the question mark in the URL. So on `site.com/search?whatever=something`, `$_GET['whatever']` would be equal to `something`. You could `kint($_GET)` to see what's in there if you'd like. https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_superglobals_get.asp

Comment: Very helpful. 

Comment: Worked great, just edit and add ```function``` before ```my_module_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {```

Comment: fair enough, done :)

Answer (score 0):

I am accepting the above answer, but adding this as it's helpful for anyone trying to accomplish the same type of thing. This preprocess function is for the general `views-view.tpl.php` file which will affect **all** views.

```
  function MY_MODULE_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  // Get the query string from the url.
  // it will be on something like ?THE_SEARCH_STRING=big+banana.
  $search_string_raw = $_GET['THE_SEARCH_STRING'];
  
  // Decode the url to remove special chars
  $search_string_decoded = urldecode($search_string_raw);

  // Add it to $variables so it's available in views-view.tpl.php
  $variables['search_string'] = $search_string_decoded;
}
```

Since this is trying to get `THE_SEARCH_STRING` on all views, this will result in an undefined index messages in the log on all view pages **except** the one where the search string exists.

I found if you want to write a  preprocess function for a specific view, the preprocess function would look like this:

`function MY_MODULE_preprocess_views_view__MY_VIEW__page(&$variables)`

There is a problem though... in Drupal 7 there is an issue where [Specific preprocess functions for theme hook suggestions are not invoked](https://www.drupal.org/node/939462). There is a workaround for it [here](http://drupal.org/node/939462#comment-4476264) which should allow you to write view specific preprocess functions for any views_view.tpl.php templates:

```
function MY_MODULE_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['view']->name)) {
    $function = 'MY_MODULE_preprocess_views_view__' . $vars['view']->name . '__' . $vars['view']->current_display;
    
    if (function_exists($function)) {
      $function($vars);
    }
  }
}
```

I wonder if the set of variables in the initial answer could be simply parented under some thing like:

`if ($view->name == 'my_view_name' && $view->current_display == 'my_display_id')`